# Unable to install Cordova android platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

6 months ago I started an Ionic project and I was never able to test on my android device because I would get errors, today I got a new computer and pulled my files down from github hoping that with a new computer my android issues would be fixed but they aren't.

Running `$ ionic cordova run android --device` results in:

cordova platform add android --save

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^7.0.0

(node:56556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^7.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dezalgo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Ionic\anonymous-social\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\correct-mkdir.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform\addHelper.js:312:25
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:56556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:56556) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

To fix this problem I've tried: `cordova platform add android@7.0.0`, `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android` but this didn't work either.

I get this error then:

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@7.0.0
(node:48276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@7.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963238 Error output:
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of firebase@^5.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN geofire@4.1.2 requires a peer of firebase@^2.4.0 || 3.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Ionic\anonymous-social\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ansistyles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Ionic\anonymous-social\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ansistyles' -> 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Ionic\anonymous-social\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.ansistyles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-29T00_34_28_046Z-debug.log
    at C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform\addHelper.js:312:25
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:48276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:48276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any ideas what I should be doing? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I also faced to similar problem like this. try removing node_modules folder and adding it again. if it doesn't work goto "C:\Users\Simon/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android" directory and  find cordova provided android version  and try cordova platform add android@x.x.x with that version. if it works please tell me.

Comment: @SudarshanaPradeep I don't seem to have a `.cordova` folder in my home directory..

Comment: Are you sure? It is a hidden folder.